# What is the correct spelling and definition of a word (sp.) "enditement"

Tags: meaning, single-word-requests, nouns, orthography

Whilst watching The Big Bang Theory (S04E11, ~06:45 in, where Howard and Stuart are talking in the Comic Book Store about Zack), I heard the following exchange:

> — Is that sarcasm?
>   — No, it's an *enditement* of the American education system.

The two characters involved are talking about a third character (who is present) who is being perceived as "stupid".

When I heard the word *enditement* I imagined it as a synonym of "example", but I cannot find a definition of a similar-sounding word that fits into the context described.

Can anyone provide the correct spelling/definition of this word?

Comment: The word is [indictment.](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/indictment)

Comment: Pronounced anywhere from /ɪn'daytmənt/ to /ṇ'dayʔmṇʔ/.

Comment: What JLG said. I think it's General Reference - as soon as I type OP's **an enditement** into the Google search box, it offers me ***four*** possible ways to complete my search term. Every one of which changes *enditement* to *indictment*.

Comment: Normally it is pronounced `/ɪnˈdaɪtmənt/`, at least phonemically.  There are various allophones possible there, including up through `[n̩ˈdʌɪʔmn̩ʔ]`, which is close to what John has written.

Answer (score 2):

The word is *indictment*, but pronounced as you spell it. The meaning is "a formal charge or accusation of a serious crime."

By "How I met Your Mother", did you mean "The Big Bang Theory"?  Howard, Stuart and Zack are characters in Big Bang, but not in HIMYM as far as I'm aware.

Comment: I wouldn’t say “pronounced as you spell it”; that seldom works in English. Things like `/ɪnˈdaɪtmənt/` or `[n̩ˈdʌɪʔmn̩ʔ]` work much better than “as you spell it”.

Comment: I think jessicar meant that "enditement", i.e., the OP spelling, is a reasonable way to have transcribed the word as heard.